# How to do combo chart in excel through vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, charts

I am trying to do a combo chart in a worksheet, through vb.net. 
The information I want to put in the chart are in the table below
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIVcN.png)
And I want to do a chart with all information from the table, but with different types of chart for each serie: stacked columns, scatter and lines as in the image below.
[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRJkl.png)

My code until now is this:

```
dim chartaux, chart, grafico as object

chartaux=worksheet6.chartobjects
chart=chartaux.add(800, 500, 800, 500)
grafico = chart.chart
```

but I don't know how to set different series to the chart. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Charty](http://charty.live) which creates charts without single line of code, that too in seconds.